# Can I delete the Watch app without unpairing Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos, apple-watch.app

I have an Apple Watch paired to my iPhone. I don't use the [apple-watch.app](/questions/tagged/apple-watch.app) often, so I'd like to remove the app from my Home screen.

Are there any consequences if I remove the [apple-watch.app](/questions/tagged/apple-watch.app) from the Home screen, such as getting my [apple-watch](/questions/tagged/apple-watch) unpaired or unable to load [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone)-dependent apps?

Comment: I'd test it, but I don't want to delete my backups lol... Wouldn't it be safer just to throw it in a junk folder? Also, as per my terrible recollection, the Apple Watch App is a default iOS app, so even if you "delete" it, it's not actually gone, just hidden - I'm not sure how this affects functionality tho.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII I realize it does that, but iOS throws an error if you try to open a URL and Safari is removed from the Home screen. I do realize it's not deleted, but it doesn't operate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The apple watch app on your iPhone will not let you remove itself unless you unpair the watch first.

So technically, no. As it is essential for the operation of the watch. What I did was just make a folder named 'Apple' and dump all Apple apps that I don't use often but somewhat essential for some things into that folder, like Weather, etc.